# Disable resolvconf permanently

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'd like to disable resolvconf permanently in Ubuntu 16.04.

Right now my /etc/network/interfaces contains

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.43.175
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.43.0
    broadcast 192.168.43.255
    gateway 192.168.43.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.43.240
    dns-search domain.local
```

As soon as the networking service starts configures the /etc/resolv.conf with

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.43.240
search domain.local
```

What I want to is to modify my /etc/resolv.conf with custom nameservers and domains without having to modify my /etc/network/interfaces and having the config permanent after networking restart or OS reboots.

I managed to make it permanent after networking restart doing

```
resolvconf --disable-update
```

But this option is not permanent after OS reboot.

Answer (score 2):

```
~/# systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
~/# service systemd-resolved stop
```

Edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and add this to [main](or change it):

```
dns=default
```

Then:

```
~/# systemctl restart network-manager
```

By the way, why set this by default? So annoying, at least let the *Manual* configuration on the nm-connection-editor take precedence over this.

Comment: This does not answer the question for Ubuntu Server where network-manager and systemd-resolved aren't installed.